# How to replace None value with values from dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have an assignment to program a simple tower defense game through printing. So I assume I'm supposed to make use of the dictionary that I was given and replace the `None` variable in my nested list called `field` to spawn a 'zombie' in the game, but I'm not sure how to do that.

This is my code that just creates a grid:

```
import random

field = [ [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
          [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
          [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
          [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
          [None, None, None, None, None, None, None] ]


zombie = {'shortform': 'ZOMBI',
          'name': 'Zombie',
          'maxHP': 15,
          'min_damage': 3,
          'max_damage': 6,
          'moves' : 1,
          'reward': 2
          }

num_rows=len(field)
num_columns=len(field[0])
row_indexes="ABCDE"

print(' {:^7}{:^5}{:^7}'.format('1','2','3'))
print(' ',end='')

for column in range(num_columns): 
    print('+-----',end='')
print('+')

for row in range(num_rows):
    print('{}'.format(row_indexes[row]), end='') # print row index
    for column in range(num_columns): #for each column,
        element = field[row][column]      
        if element is None:      #print spacings
            print('|     ' , end='') 
        else:                     #print monster name
            print('|' + element[0], end='')
    print('|') #end row

    print(' ', end='') #spacing for 2nd | row 
    for column in range(num_columns):
        element = field[row][column]
        if element is None:  #print spacing agn
            print('|     ' , end='')
        else:                     #print monster helth
            print('|' + element[1], end='')
    print('|') #end row

    print(' ', end='') #spacing for letter
    for column in range(num_columns):
        print('+-----', end = '')
    print('+')#end of row

row_spawn=random.randint(0,4)
field[row_spawn][5]=zombie.get('shortform')
```

This is how it should look like but the zombi spawning in a random lane:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't change much in your code. Just moved most part of the code to a function.
In your code you create the field, then draw your field and THEN you change the field and add a zombie, but this field never gets printed.

At the code below you create a field and the zombie dict, then you wrap your whole code where drawing the field to a function which takes the field and zombie as input and returns the current state of the field and the zombi dict.

At the bottom I made a loop, where a zombie is spawned 5 times in a random row and a random column. Also I added a `current_HP` to the zombie dict, which decreases every round by 1 (just for demonstration).
In case a zombie gets spawned in a position where already a zombie is placed, the values just get overwritten.
When accessing the value of a dict, you use `dict.get()` preferred if you don't know if that key exists, but since you create the dict you can just directly access it like `dict[key]`.

If you have any question feel free to ask!

```
field = [ [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
          [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
          [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
          [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
          [None, None, None, None, None, None, None] ]


zombie = {'shortform': 'ZOMBI',
          'name': 'Zombie',
          'current_HP': 15,
          'maxHP': 15,
          'min_damage': 3,
          'max_damage': 6,
          'moves' : 1,
          'reward': 2
          }

def draw(field):
    num_rows=len(field)
    num_columns=len(field[0])
    row_indexes="ABCDE"

    print(' {:^7}{:^5}{:^7}'.format('1','2','3'))
    print(' ',end='')

    for column in range(num_columns): 
        print('+-----',end='')
    print('+')

    for row in range(num_rows):
        print('{}'.format(row_indexes[row]), end='') # print row index
        for column in range(num_columns): #for each column,
            element = field[row][column]      
            if element is None:      #print spacings
                print('|     ' , end='') 
            else:                     #print monster name
                print('|' + element[0], end='')
        print('|') #end row

        print(' ', end='') #spacing for 2nd | row 
        for column in range(num_columns):
            element = field[row][column]
            if element is None:  #print spacing agn
                print('|     ' , end='')
            else:                     #print monster helth
                print('|' + element[1], end='')
        print('|') #end row

        print(' ', end='') #spacing for letter
        for column in range(num_columns):
            print('+-----', end = '')
        print('+')#end of row
    return field

for _ in range(5):
    row_spawn = random.randint(0,4)
    col_spawn = random.randint(0,6)
    
    #next you change at one position of the field the value to a tuple with [1] name [2] health
    field[row_spawn][col_spawn]=(zombie['shortform'], f"{zombie['current_HP']}/{zombie['maxHP']}")
    
    # now call the function with the updated field
    field, zombie = draw(field, zombie)
    
    # HP decreases every round
    zombie['current_HP'] -= 1
```

Comment: thanks! what about if i add another function to add a unit that isnt a zombie?  basically does that mean i my new unit is the 'zombie' when i call the draw function again? and if i get a user input on where to place it on the map Eg. D3 , how should i go about that?

Comment: about the input where to place them, I believe you figure that out ;) there needs to be a little challenge for you. about the different players. you could make a function which returns a dictionary (like that called "zombie") where you have different input arguments which will be assigned to the keys. Like that you "create" a player by calling this function. At the moment the draw function has nothing to do with zombie or any other player. you just need to be aware that before calling the draw function you want to update/change your field, that is the main part

Comment: Zombie was only in the draw function because I thought you want to implement some game logic inside this function. then you will need it. Maybe the name of the function is chosen poorly. you can also call it `def game()` if it should do more than just draw the field.